# scale variable constant within group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

So I am not sure how to phrase this question but it's pretty basic. I would of course like to find an elegant way to include this in a `dplyr`-esque pipe.

Let's say that I have a data frame

```
set.seed(1)
dd <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,2), c(3,5)),
                 x = rnorm(8), 
                 d = rep(c(0.3, 0.5), c(3,5)))
```

I would like to replace `d` by a scaled version, i.e. instead of 0.3 and 0.5, I would like to have

```
> as.numeric(scale(c(0.3, 0.5)))
[1] -0.7071068  0.7071068
```

The only problem when I use `scale` in the pipe is that the larger group (`id = 2`) receives more weight, and the values obtained are

```
> dd %>% 
+   mutate(scale_d = scale(d))
  id          x   d    scale_d
1  1 -0.6264538 0.3 -1.2076147
2  1  0.1836433 0.3 -1.2076147
3  1 -0.8356286 0.3 -1.2076147
4  2  1.5952808 0.5  0.7245688
5  2  0.3295078 0.5  0.7245688
6  2 -0.8204684 0.5  0.7245688
7  2  0.4874291 0.5  0.7245688
8  2  0.7383247 0.5  0.7245688
```

I feel that this should be a quite simple problem, so maybe there is a simple solution out there?

Comment: How about `dd$d = scale(dd$d)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily `nest` x:

```
library(tidyverse)

dd %>% 
    nest(x) %>% 
    mutate(scale_d = scale(d)) %>% 
    unnest()

## # A tibble: 8 × 4
##      id     d    scale_d          x
##   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
## 1     1   0.3 -0.7071068 -0.6264538
## 2     1   0.3 -0.7071068  0.1836433
## 3     1   0.3 -0.7071068 -0.8356286
## 4     2   0.5  0.7071068  1.5952808
## 5     2   0.5  0.7071068  0.3295078
## 6     2   0.5  0.7071068 -0.8204684
## 7     2   0.5  0.7071068  0.4874291
## 8     2   0.5  0.7071068  0.7383247
```